# How to ignore values that are negative when plotting a line plot with matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, data-visualization, line-plot

I have a matrix where some values have `-1` as an indication that there was an error. Normally I would just use `ylim([0 100])` to not show these values in my graph, but when using line graph the connection will still drop down to the point. I want a chart that consists of lines, not a scatter plot. Is there a simple way of ignoring negative values when plotting a line and only connect positive values when using the plot function in MATLAB?

I have written a small example program which behaves similarly, but the way I use seems a little "too complicated" and I want to know if there is an easier way to achieve this. It works fine as I put the values to `NaN`, and now the `x` and `y` values are the same amount. However deleting or sorting out the values from the vector will lead to different amount of `x` and `y` values.

I was hoping for a modification or a flag or something.

```
x = 2*rand(10) - rand(10)
xx = 10:10:100;

figure;
for i=1:length(x)
    for j=1:length(x(i,:))
        if x(i,j) < 0
           x(i,j) = NaN; 
        end
    end
end

plot(xx,x)
```

Please note that this is only an example, the whole code would be too large to post here.

When having non-corresponding `x`-values (so that the plot function simply uses `1,2,3...` and so on for the corresponding `y` values) this can be achieved by using

```
plot(x(x>0))
```

In this case, the corresponding values are different, in the real code they are measured data, here I simply use a 10th step for simplification.

```
x = 2*rand(10) - rand(10)
xx = 10:10:100;

plot(xx,x(x>0))
```

The above code will error with the message "Vectors must be the same length".

Comment: You have a vector which you wish to plot and it contains negative values which you want to remove ?

Comment: I do not want to remove the negative numbers, I want them not to show up in the plot , so that when using a line plot the line does not connect to this value.

Comment: I just want to be sure I understand correctly. You want to plot a vector without its negative values ?

Comment: Sry I am not good at writing problems correctly - but yes that is what I want

Comment: Have you tried to make them NaN?

Comment: Yes, I edited the code so that it uses NaN, this works fine but looks a little bit questionable to me, however it suits my needs. Just want to know if there is maybe a more advanced way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just like using `NaN` instead of negative values, only that the original vector is not modified at all. You might notice that this solution is vectorized.

```
y = 2*randn(10,1) - randn(10,1);
figure(); plot(1:numel(y), y./(y<=0) );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! When I execute this code I only get a blank figure, anybody else experience the same ? I am using Matlab R2016 b

Comment: @Kev1n91 that's the thing with randomness... Just run it several times until you get some visible lines...

Comment: Of course, d'oh. However does this solution address the corresponding x-values ? (Note there was an edit to the question to point this out)

Comment: @Kev1n91 Seeing how we have `numel(y)` `x` values, it can't really go wrong. You can also play around with `plot(linspace(XMIN,XMAX,numel(y)),y)` if you need evenly spaced `x`'s.

Comment: I suppose this could be simplified slightly by replacing `(1-(y<0))` with `(y>=0)`

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [50, -1, 10, 5, 8, 22, -1];
b = a > 0;
c = a(b);
```

**Output:**

```
c
[50, 10, 5, 8, 22]
```

Now you can plot c

```
[~, s] = size(c);
xx = 1:1:s;
```

You could also do it directly without saving the calculation and modifying it. just plot it.
`plot(x(x>0))`

Comment: Or if OP doesnt want to modify the data, `plot(x(x>0))`

Comment: @AnderBiguri, true but first method will probably be more clear to him.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I made an edit to my post. I have corresponding x values, if I change it like the post is shown then the amount of x values to y values is off. Even with a negativevalue (-1) there is still a corresponding one. I would need to change them both and erase the corresponding value

Comment: @Kev1n91 this could be applied for matrix as well. Could you write an example in your post then ? of input and expected output ?

Comment: @Kev1n91
Count the number of elements which are left, create a new `xx` vector and plot.